# PHP DocuSing: after updating to Laravel 9 getting the error non successful HTTP code [400] User not found for JWT

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt, docusignapi

I've integrated DocuSign API with my Laravel App few months back with JWT Authentication. It was working without any issues so far.
Two days ago we updated our app to Laravel 9 and since then getting this error while using the DocuSign API:

```
Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [400] with response Body: O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:5:"error";s:13:"invalid_grant";s:17:"error_description";s:14:"user_not_found";}
```

I've checked the configuration for Integration Key, User GuiId. Everything is matched and we didn't change it. So wondering why we're getting this error? Is it related to Laravel upgrade?
I googled but didn't see any specific issue which matches with our issues.

Anyone else getting the same after upgrading to Laravel to 9? Any assist from DocuSign team on this issue would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubt this error is directly connected to the Laravel upgrade.
This error means that you provided the wrong **userID** (GUID) when requesting JWT.

Make sure:

The userID is from the same environment (Production vs. Development env).
That means you need to check the URLs and make sure they match as well (Prod vs. Dev)

Make sure this GUID matches the account you are using.

Just in case, double check your RSA private key. You cannot see the value, so you may need to generate a new one.

Comment: I also believe it's not due to Laravel upgrade, that's why checked the user GUID and all. I saved the API key and details to env file. I'll test it now with hardcoded keys to JWT connection function. Let's see what happen.

Comment: What about the URL?

Comment: "AuthorizationEndpoint": "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth",
    "TokenEndpoint": "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token",

Comment: These are for the developer env. Without the -d for prod. Make sure you get the right ones

Comment: it's working fine when hard coding the user GUID. Not sure why it's not taking env file value. I'll investigate more. Thanks for your tips and prompt reply!

Comment: @shah - In the worst case scenario you can set up Fiddler to catch your JWT Assertion over the wire, and decode that (jwt.io will do it if you can't do it yourself) to see what your application is actually sending out.

Comment: Shah, maybe share your PHP code? that way we can try to help better

Comment: Hey @Inbar, I was on holiday, so extremely sorry couldn't reply to your comments. All looks good now, we could read the value from the env file. It was related to our internal deployment script. Thanks again for your excellent support. It was really helpful.